# How can I get h1 innerText in JavaScript without the innerText of its child?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I want to get the innerText of `<h1>`  without the `innerText` inside the span... this is the HTML of page:

```js
var title = document.querySelector('div.col-md-8.info-header h1');
title = title && title.innerText;
console.log(title);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 header">
  <div class="col-md-8 info-header">
    <h1> This note is for h1 tag!!!!!! <span> this note is insidespan v226hql!!! </span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

but this will return the `innerText` of both `<h1>` and `<span>`.

what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you select the parent, you'll have to select its child *text node*, and get the contents of that node:

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('div.col-md-8.info-header h1');
const text = h1.childNodes[0].textContent;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 header">
  <div class="col-md-8 info-header">
    <h1> This note is for h1 tag!!!!!! <span> this note is insidespan v226hql!!! </span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately there's no way to navigate *directly* to a text node with a query string, so you have to go through the `childNodes` first.

Comment: Won't this contain the inner span content they want to avoid?

Comment: No, you can press Run Code Snippet to see it in action - it results in only `This note is for h1 tag!!!!!! `, as you can see in the snippet output console. `childNodes[0]` selects the first child node of the parent, and the first child node is the text node that OP wants to get the content of.

Comment: It will not get all the text,if `h1` have some text after `span` el,it will not include.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm on mobile. It works for this specific case. I had been thinking in general terms. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var mainElement = document.getElementById("id_of_h1"),
    innerElements = mainElement.firstChild,
    innerTexts = [];

while (innerElements) {
    if (innerElements.nodeType == 3) {
        innerTexts.push(innerElements.data);
    }
    innerElements = innerElements.nextSibling;
}

var finalResult = innerTexts.join("");
```

finaresult will contain the intertext of the top element only.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have `<h1>hello <span>another</span> world` and need to get all text except html elements- `hello world` not `hello another world`,then you need to this way

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('div.col-md-8.info-header h1');
const el = h1.childNodes;
let result = "";
for(i=0;i<el.length;i++){
   if(el[i].nodeName == '#text'){
     result+=el[i].textContent;
   }
}
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 header">
  <div class="col-md-8 info-header">
    <h1> This note is for h1 tag!!!!!! <span> this note is insidespan v226hql!!! </span> extra text without tag
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```